# PHP upload to blob on the fly

Tags: php, mysql, input, upload, blob

I have a simple input form which contains an input type="file" with name="pdf_statement".

I want to be able to upload the content and insert into the database on the fly. As this is only a test file I am not worried about security (i will add once the functionality is in place).

I have read http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-contents.php but cannot get this to work. I get errors *fopen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given* and *stream_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given*.

I'm sorry if this is blindingly obvious but for someone who is learning I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
<?php

include('session.php');

$provider      =$_POST['provider_id'];
$trd_period    =$_POST['trading_period_month'];
$pdf_statement =stream_get_contents(fopen($_FILES['pdf_statement'], 'r'));

$sql_qry="update rd_provider_statement
          set (pdf_statment='".$pdf_statement."', creation_user_id='SCO')
          where  provider='".$provider."' and trading_period_month='".$trd_period."'";
$sql_err_no=sql_select($sql_qry,$sql_res,$sql_row_count,$sql_err,$sql_uerr);    

?>
```

Comment: you want to access the $_FILES['pdf_statement']['tmp_name']

Comment: Database space is a more expensive resource in most environments than regular disk. Why not save the PDFs to a filesystem and store pointers in your database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open the file in binary mode:

```
fopen($_FILES['pdf_statement']['tmp_name'], 'rb')
```

or you can just use `file_get_contents()` instead.

```
$pdf_statement = file_get_contents($_FILES['pdf_statement']['tmp_name']);
```

You also need to sanitize your input. Use `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Comment: Thank you both, if I echo $pdf_statement i get a load of characters so I know it is being read properly however none of the columns are being updated in the table?

Comment: Did you try checking the error variables to see if there's any errors in your query?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'i???????v??c?@?lÑ§?1???#?=?c?Åˆ????X-????Ã³??-??l??{??V???????7?Æµ?Jy?m*a' at line 2 - its something to do with the way the binary string is processed. im using set pdf_statement='".$pdf_statement."'

Comment: You also need to sanitize your input. Use `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Answer (score 0):

`$_FILES['pdf_statement']` is an array, not a string containing a filepath you can pass to `fopen`. You also need to open the file in binary mode.

```
$pdf_statement = stream_get_contents(fopen($_FILES['pdf_statement']['tmp_name'], 'rb'));
```

It's worth pointing out that using the database to store file uploads is not a very good idea. The file system is a much better place for this information.